# How to use Windows QT to call WSL cmd?

Tags: python, qt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm new to QT and Windows environment programming and tried to integrate some stuffs I developed in Python with another guy in QT. My python code deals with .ods and .xls files by using linux packages gnumeric and libreoffice. I found that WSL may be a convenient way to run my original Python code and it went well after I installed WSL2 Ubuntu.

Then I installed QT5.15.2 with MinGW and try to run my Python code after click a button. I tested in QT Creator and found this line works: `QProcess::execute("cmd /c mkdir C:\\Test");` that creates a folder in C. However, this line won't work: `QProcess::execute("cmd /c wsl -h >> res.txt");` It can't recognize what `wsl` is. But I also test the QT MinGW terminal and it recognized `wsl`. Why it can't recognize in exe? Do I need to select different compiler or debugger? Or any other suggestion such as Docker for this kind of integration? Thank you~

Comment: ***It can't recognize what wsl*** Maybe you need to specify a full path to the wsl executable

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you. I tried to add the full path with `C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe ` but it still not recognized.

Comment: > It can't recognize what `wsl` is.

What is the error message you are getting? works fine with me!

Comment: @C137 "wsl is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: @C137 After I change to MinGW 64-bit it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with C

system(QString("wsl.exe").toStdString().c_str());

Comment: Thank you~ Finally it's because MinGW 32-bit cannot recognize but 64-bit works.